# this Java UUID5 implementation not passing unit test

Tags: java, uuid

I couldn't find a self-contained UUID5 implementation for Java, so I tried rolling this solution below. It passes some of my unit tests but fails others. Any obvious bugs in this?

```
public static UUID UUID5(UUID namespace, String name) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        throw new InternalError("SHA-1 not supported");
    }

    byte[] namespaceBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(namespace.getMostSignificantBits()).putLong(namespace.getLeastSignificantBits()).array();
    byte[] nameBytes;
    try {
        nameBytes = name.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new InternalError("UTF-8 encoding not supported");
    }

    byte[] toHashify = new byte[namespaceBytes.length + nameBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(namespaceBytes, 0, toHashify, 0, namespaceBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(nameBytes, 0, toHashify, namespaceBytes.length, nameBytes.length);

    byte[] data = md.digest(toHashify);
    data = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0, 16); // Wikipedia says "Note that the 160 bit SHA-1 hash is truncated to 128 bits to make the length work out."

    data[6]  &= 0x0f;  /* clear version        */
    data[6]  |= 0x50;  /* set to version 5     TODO is this the correct way to do it     */
    data[8]  &= 0x3f;  /* clear variant        */
    data[8]  |= 0x80;  /* set to IETF variant  */

    long msb = 0;
    long lsb = 0;
    assert data.length == 16 : "data must be 16 bytes in length";
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {msb = (msb << 8) | (data[i] & 0xff);}
    for (int i=8; i<16; i++)
        {lsb = (lsb << 8) | (data[i] & 0xff);}

    return new UUID(msb, lsb);
}
```

Comment: You might want to post your unit tests as well.

Comment: Check this line: `data = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0, 128);` ... The hash is 128 *bits* but you're padding the array to 128 *bytes*.

Comment: @sehrope  Thanks, I fixed that, but it's still passing and failing the same tests as before

Comment: @Dave It seems like the tests that fail are where the first character (half-byte) in the namespace is a "0"

Comment: Arggh I think some of my tests might be wrong... Time to recompute all of them :-(

Answer (score 4):

Use [Apache Commons Id](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/), more specifically [UUID.nameUUIDFromString](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/apidocs/org/apache/commons/id/uuid/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromString%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.id.uuid.UUID,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
UUID uuid5 = UUID.nameUUIDFromString("www.ford.com", 
       UUID.fromString("078d4e79-244f-440e-844d-9454eadfd411"),
       UUID.SHA1_ENCODING);
```

`UUID.SHA1_ENCODING` will generate version 5 UUIDs.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Still curious if someone is able to answer this question with a bug fix to my hand-rolled code also.

Comment: Actually, I can't find any way to download Commons Id!! The releases page doesn't have any: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/downloads.html And the link to the source repo is broken: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jakarta/commons/sandbox/id/

Comment: Ok, I found some sketchy "JAR search" site that has Commons Id; is there a more legitimate place than this to get it from? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsidjar.htm

Comment: This is still a [sandbox](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox.html) component with no official release. Follow the link in [this page](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/source-repository.html) for the [svn repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/id/trunk/). Just checkout the project and use Maven or Ant to build the jar.