# How to make a Type 5 UUID in Java?

Tags: java, uuid

In python, to make a Type 5 UUID we can simply do:

```
import uuid
print uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, 'my string')
```

Looking through the [java documentation for java.util.UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), I don't see how to do it. First off, type 5 isn't mentioned. They do have a Type 3, but the signature is:

```
 nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] name)
 Static factory to retrieve a type 3 (name based) UUID based on the specified byte array.
```

**How can we make a Type 5 UUID in Java?**

Comment: Maybe this helps https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/herd/uuid/0.0.10/module-doc/api/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this Java UUID5 implementation not passing unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501357/this-java-uuid5-implementation-not-passing-unit-test)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can implement it yourself by following the code proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776880/1452094.
However this does require some fiddling since the j.u.UUID constructor takes longs.

As of `Java 8` the standard library does not seem to support type 5. But third party libraries like "Apache Commons Id" have UUID implementations that do support it.

EDIT: Here is a fully functional implementation:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class UUIDType5 {
    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_DNS = UUID.fromString("6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8");
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_URL = UUID.fromString("6ba7b811-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8");
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_OID = UUID.fromString("6ba7b812-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8");
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_X500 = UUID.fromString("6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8");

    public static UUID nameUUIDFromNamespaceAndString(UUID namespace, String name) {
        return nameUUIDFromNamespaceAndBytes(namespace, Objects.requireNonNull(name, "name == null").getBytes(UTF8));
    }

    public static UUID nameUUIDFromNamespaceAndBytes(UUID namespace, byte[] name) {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            throw new InternalError("SHA-1 not supported");
        }
        md.update(toBytes(Objects.requireNonNull(namespace, "namespace is null")));
        md.update(Objects.requireNonNull(name, "name is null"));
        byte[] sha1Bytes = md.digest();
        sha1Bytes[6] &= 0x0f;  /* clear version        */
        sha1Bytes[6] |= 0x50;  /* set to version 5     */
        sha1Bytes[8] &= 0x3f;  /* clear variant        */
        sha1Bytes[8] |= 0x80;  /* set to IETF variant  */
        return fromBytes(sha1Bytes);
    }

    private static UUID fromBytes(byte[] data) {
        // Based on the private UUID(bytes[]) constructor
        long msb = 0;
        long lsb = 0;
        assert data.length >= 16;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            msb = (msb << 8) | (data[i] & 0xff);
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++)
            lsb = (lsb << 8) | (data[i] & 0xff);
        return new UUID(msb, lsb);
    }

    private static byte[] toBytes(UUID uuid) {
        // inverted logic of fromBytes()
        byte[] out = new byte[16];
        long msb = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
        long lsb = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            out[i] = (byte) ((msb >> ((7 - i) * 8)) & 0xff);
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++)
            out[i] = (byte) ((lsb >> ((15 - i) * 8)) & 0xff);
        return out;
    }
}
```

To verify it works I ran the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UUID test = UUIDType5.nameUUIDFromNamespaceAndString(NAMESPACE_URL, "google.com");
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(test.version());
}
```

This created the output:

> fedb2fa3-8f5c-5189-80e6-f563dd1cb8f9
>
> 5

Verified against the official python implementation:

> >>> print(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, 'google.com'))
>
> fedb2fa3-8f5c-5189-80e6-f563dd1cb8f9

Comment: Thanks I will check out rolling my own. [Apache Commons Id doesn't appear to have any official releases yet.](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/downloads.html)

Comment: Thats what I get for quickly checking if any of the big support libraries supported it :P

Comment: You can refer to the implementation of the type 3 UUID: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/UUID.java#UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29 - The differences are that the digest is "sha1", it digests first the bytes of the namespace UUID and then the namespace name and instread of `md5Bytes[6]  |= 0x30;` it needs to be `sha1Bytes[6]  |= 0x50;`

Comment: I have a big database of long strings that are unique identifiers. I was able to use this program to convert them into Long integers using `UUIDType5.nameUUIDFromNamespaceAndString(UUIDType5.NAMESPACE_URL, myStrId).getMostSignificantBits() & Long.MAX_VALUE` and all 3 million IDs continue to be unique.

Comment: I would use a tested and benchmarked library rather than writing my own code. See other answers for libraries.

Answer (score 3):

In the case someone else needs a library that generates version 5 UUIDs.

```java
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1("google.com");
```

```java
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1(UuidCreator.NAMESPACE_URL, "google.com");
```

https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the main contributor of this library.

Answer (score 1):

The java-uuid-generator (JUG) library can generate version 5 UUIDs:

```
UUID uuid = Generators.nameBasedgenerator().generate("string to hash"); // Version 5
```

https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator