# Generate UUID5 in NiFi

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi, uuid

In NiFi, I have a flow file with an attribute `RSID`. I need to generate a UUID v5 based on `RSID` and add it as an attribute to the flow file. This uuid needs to be based on `RSID` because some reports will have the same `RSID` and need to thus have the same UUID5.

I've seen some methods in Groovy that will generate a random uuid, but not v5 nor based on a string. Is this possible to do in Groovy/NiFi? If so, how would this be done? I'm very new to Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do this with Groovy and NiFi using the ExecuteScript processor. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230276/how-to-make-a-type-5-uuid-in-java) includes the code for generating a UUID v5 which you can apply to your `RSID` namespace. If you want some pointers on using the NiFi API from ExecuteScript, feel free to check out [my cookbook series](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922), hopefully it will help you assemble a working solution.

I have also [written a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6791) to add a UUID5 function to NiFi Expression Language, to make this easier.